# API Management custom user metadata

Tags: azure-api-management

Api management provides a nice utility `context.User.Id` to get the gateway id for the current user.

What is the simplest/best way to extend the current user object to include custom metadata?

For example we want to be able to send a user setting lets call-it `external-id` upstream via a custom header.

Answer (score 1):

A hack is to use context.User.Note property to store the additional metadata. You can store the metadata as JSON and deserialize in policy to get the custom property.

Answer (score 0):

So, you can use `set-header` policy to add the custom metadata to the request.

Comment: Thanks J.J, and will solve one part of the example usage. The question is really -- What is the simplest/best way to extend the current user object to include custom metadata?

Comment: I believe the user object is readonly so you cannot extend it.

Comment: hmm. there is no claims based way to use the user context? to retrieve more metadata? seems limiting as the user is a pretty core concept. Am I missing something? -- thanks for responding by the way. You're all I have to bounce ideas off. #lonelyplanet

Comment: You cant extend the user object. You can use send request policy to get external-id or other metadata by passing the user id within the request and use the response. Additionally, you can cache the results to avoid IO.

Comment: thanks that is what we did do at the end of the day.. we first used properties in the api gateway, now we are using a request to cosmos db. Can you please add this as the answer and i'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You cant extend the user object. You can use send request policy to get external-id or other metadata by passing the user id within the request and use the response. Additionally, you can cache the results to avoid IO